# Creating an image without storing it as a local file

Tags: php, image, jpeg, gd

Here's my situation - I want to create a resized jpeg image from a user uploaded image, and then send it to S3 for storage, but am looking to avoid writing the resized jpeg to the disk and then reloading it for the S3 request.

Is there a way to do this completely in memory, with the image data JPEG formatted, saved in a variable?

Answer (score 13):

Most people using PHP choose either [ImageMagick](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php)  or [Gd2](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php)

I've never used Imagemagick; the Gd2 method:

```
<?php

// assuming your uploaded file was 'userFileName'

if ( ! is_uploaded_file(validateFilePath($_FILES[$userFileName]['tmp_name'])) ) {
    trigger_error('not an uploaded file', E_USER_ERROR);
}
$srcImage = imagecreatefromjpeg( $_FILES[$userFileName]['tmp_name'] );

// Resize your image (copy from srcImage to dstImage)
imagecopyresampled($dstImage, $srcImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, RESIZED_IMAGE_WIDTH, RESIZED_IMAGE_HEIGHT, imagesx($srcImage), imagesy($srcImage));

// Storing your resized image in a variable
ob_start(); // start a new output buffer
  imagejpeg( $dstImage, NULL, JPEG_QUALITY);
  $resizedJpegData = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean(); // stop this output buffer

// free up unused memmory (if images are expected to be large)
unset($srcImage);
unset($dstImage);

// your resized jpeg data is now in $resizedJpegData
// Use your Undesigned method calls to store the data.

// (Many people want to send it as a Hex stream to the DB:)
$dbHandle->storeResizedImage( $resizedJpegData );
?>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 8):

This can be done using the GD library and output buffering. I don't know how efficient this is compared with other methods, but it doesn't require explicit creation of files.

```
//$image contains the GD image resource you want to store

ob_start();
imagejpeg($image);
$jpeg_file_contents = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

//now send $jpeg_file_contents to S3
```

Answer (score 6):

Once you've got the JPEG in memory (using [ImageMagick](http://ie.php.net/imagick), [GD](http://ie.php.net/gd), or your graphic library of choice), you'll need to upload the object from memory to S3.

Many PHP S3 classes seem to only support file uploads, but the one at [Undesigned](http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class) seems to do what we're after here -

```
// Manipulate image - assume ImageMagick, so $im is image object
$im = new Imagick();
// Get image source data
$im->readimageblob($image_source);

// Upload an object from a resource (requires size):
$s3->putObject($s3->inputResource($im->getimageblob(), $im->getSize()), 
                  $bucketName, $uploadName, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ);
```

If you're using GD instead, you can use
[imagecreatefromstring](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php) to read an image in from a stream, but I'm not sure whether you can get the size of the resulting object, as required by `s3->inputResource` above - [getimagesize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) returns the height, width, etc, but not the size of the image resource.

Comment: I should have clarified - I am using Undesigned's S3 class.
Do you know a GD way of doing what you posted above? Before I jump to installing imagemagick, would be nice to know if I absolutely need to.

Comment: My GD is a bit sketchy - I know you can read the image in similarly to ImageMagick, not sure about getting the object size though - been a while since I went through the docs and couldn't see anything there. ImageMagick is well worth the install though IMO!

Comment: imagesx and imagesy returns the width/height of an image ressource.

Answer (score 5):

Pretty late to the game on this one, but if you are using the the S3 library mentioned by ConroyP and Imagick you should use the putObjectString() method instead of putObject() due the fact getImageBlob returns a string.  Example that finally worked for me:

```
$headers = array(
    'Content-Type' => 'image/jpeg'
);
$s3->putObjectString($im->getImageBlob(), $bucket, $file_name, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ, array(), $headers);
```

I struggled with this one a bit, hopefully it helps someone else!

Comment: I have been struggling with this for over 3 months and saw some light when I read this. However, this does not work for me. `getImageBlob` appears to return an empty string whereas `writeImage` to disk works. Any idea?

Comment: I like this s3 library, it's small and simple. However it didn't support s3 folders as far as I could see.

Answer (score 5):

Realize this is an old thread, but I spent some time banging my head against the wall on this today, and thought I would capture my solution here for the next guy.

This method uses [AWS SDK for PHP 2](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/) and GD for the image resize (Imagick could also be easily used).

```
require_once('vendor/aws/aws-autoloader.php');

use Aws\Common\Aws;

define('AWS_BUCKET', 'your-bucket-name-here');

// Configure AWS factory 
$aws = Aws::factory(array(
    'key' => 'your-key-here',
    'secret' => 'your-secret-here',
    'region' => 'your-region-here'
));

// Create reference to S3
$s3 = $aws->get('S3');
$s3->createBucket(array('Bucket' => AWS_BUCKET));
$s3->waitUntilBucketExists(array('Bucket' => AWS_BUCKET));
$s3->registerStreamWrapper();

// Do your GD resizing here (omitted for brevity)

// Capture image stream in output buffer
ob_start();
imagejpeg($imageRes);
$imageFileContents = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

// Send stream to S3
$context = stream_context_create(
  array(
    's3' => array(
      'ContentType'=> 'image/jpeg'
    )
  )
);
$s3Stream = fopen('s3://'.AWS_BUCKET.'/'.$filename, 'w', false, $context);
fwrite($s3Stream, $imageFileContents);
fclose($s3Stream);

unset($context, $imageFileContents, $s3Stream);
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks Bart. Is there some response object that I can use to find out if the transaction failed?

Comment: Per the PHP Docs (http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php), fwrite will return false on error.

Answer (score 4):

The Imagemagick library will let you do that. There are plenty of PHP wrappers like [this](http://uk.php.net/imagick) one around for it (there's even [example code](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php#78717) for what you want to do on that page ;) )

Answer (score 1):

I encounter the same problem, using openstack object store and [php-opencloud](https://github.com/php-opencloud/openstack) library.

Here is my solution, which does **not** use the `ob_start` and `ob_end_clean` function, but store the image in memory and in temp file. [The size of the memory and the temp file may be adapted at runtime](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php).

```
// $image is a resource created by gd2
var_dump($image); // resource(2) of type (gd)

// we create a resource in memory + temp file 
$tmp = fopen('php://temp', '$r+');

// we write the image into our resource
\imagejpeg($image, $tmp);

// the image is now in $tmp, and you can handle it as a stream
// you can, then, upload it as a stream (not tested but mentioned in doc http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/service-s3.html#uploading-from-a-stream)
$s3->putObject(array(
   'Bucket' => $bucket,
   'Key'    => 'data_from_stream.txt',
   'Body'   => $tmp
));

// or, for the ones who prefers php-opencloud :
$container->createObject([
    'name'  => 'data_from_stream.txt',
    'stream' => \Guzzle\Psr7\stream_for($tmp),
    'contentType' => 'image/jpeg'
]);
```

---

About `php://temp` ([from the official documentation of php](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php)):

> php://memory and php://temp are read-write streams that allow temporary data to be stored in a file-like wrapper. The only difference between the two is that php://memory will always store its data in memory, whereas php://temp will use a temporary file once the amount of data stored hits a predefined limit (the default is 2 MB). The location of this temporary file is determined in the same way as the sys_get_temp_dir() function.
>
> The memory limit of php://temp can be controlled by appending /maxmemory:NN, where NN is the maximum amount of data to keep in memory before using a temporary file, in bytes.

Answer (score -1):

Maye by using the [GD library](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php).

There is a function to copy out a part of an image and resize it. Of course the part could be the whole image, that way you would only resize it.

see [imagecopyresampled](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php)