# how can i get the name of imagick temp file after imageresize

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

Using imagemagick, I need to resize images of multiple sizes (800px, 400px, 50px).

And I do not want to save these image locally because I need to upload the image to Amazon S3 anyways.

For example, after the following code

```
$im->resizeImage(0, 800, imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1, FALSE);
```

$im->getImageFilename() still returns the original temp file uploaded prior to resizing. What I need is the temp file name & path after the resizing so that I can upload it straight to Amazon S3 without doing writeImage() locally. To save time and space.

Any suggestion?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189368/create-a-jpeg-in-php-w-o-creating-a-file/189410#189410

this is the answer i was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "temp file". ImageMagick does operations in memory. If you want the image to be written out to a file you need to call `$im->writeImage`.