# is there some way of make a gd image resource into a file stream resource?

Tags: php, resources, stream, gd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating an image without storing it as a local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189368/creating-an-image-without-storing-it-as-a-local-file)

i need create a image with gd and upload it to anoter server with curl in php .

so i met a problem : a gd image resource can't use as a file stream resource with curl.

is there some way of make a gd image resource into a file stream resource ?

--update--

the local disk is not writeable .

Comment: Why don't you save it to disk first?

Comment: local path is not writeable .

Comment: What platform are you on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You won't be able to use it is as a resource, but this should work to capture a JPEG of the image into a local variable.

```
ob_start();
imagejpeg($image);
$jpeg_image = ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: thanks for your help ! i got string in your way and made it into stream with tmpfile().:)