# PHP Image Crop upload cropped image

Tags: php, image, amazon-web-services

So I have a scenario where I have to upload a cropped image to AWS.

First, I have the basic image upload working (AWS putbucket and all) so that's not the issue.

I also have the cropping of the image working (using imgAreaSelect) so that is also not the issue.

On the PHP side I also grab the image from the $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] and create a new cropped image (using code similar to found at http://www.codeforest.net/how-to-crop-an-image-using-jquery-and-php.

However  I need a way to grab the new image created on the last line

```
 imagejpeg($new, $new_filename, 95);
```

into $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] in the aws upload here

```
    $s3->putObject(array(       
    'Body'   => fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'r'),
));
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189368/creating-an-image-without-storing-it-as-a-local-file

Comment: So:using GD


```
ob_start(); // start a new output buffer
  imagejpeg( $dstImage, NULL, JPEG_QUALITY);
  $resizedJpegData = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean(); // stop this output buffer

// free up unused memmory (if images are expected to be large)
unset($srcImage);
unset($dstImage);

// your resized jpeg data is now in $resizedJpegData
// Use your Undesigned method calls to store the data.

// (Many people want to send it as a Hex stream to the DB:)
$dbHandle->storeResizedImage( bin2hex($resizedJpegData) );
```



'Body'   => fopen($dbHandle, 'r'),

Comment: See my answer below (comment didn't format)

Answer (score 0):

So:using GD

```
ob_start(); // start a new output buffer
  imagejpeg( $dstImage, NULL, JPEG_QUALITY);
  $resizedJpegData = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean(); // stop this output buffer

 // free up unused memmory (if images are expected to be large)
unset($srcImage);
unset($dstImage);

// your resized jpeg data is now in $resizedJpegData
// Use your Undesigned method calls to store the data.

// (Many people want to send it as a Hex stream to the DB:)
$dbHandle->storeResizedImage( bin2hex($resizedJpegData) );


'Body'   => fopen($dbHandle, 'r'),
```