# Converting images to png without creating new file in php

Tags: php, image-processing, png

I'm trying to convert uploaded images to png in order to strip out any unwanted malicious content before saving them on amazon s3. I don't want to create any new files on my server, just to send the newly created png file.

Currently my code looks like this ($photos is is an array made from $_FILES['photo'] which could contain multiple photos. $x is stepping through them):

```
$result = $client->putObject(array(
    'Bucket'     => $bucket,
    'Key'        => $file_name,
    'SourceFile' => $photos["tmp_name"][$x]
     ));
```

I'd like to do something first like this:

```
$newPNG = becomePNGfile($photos["tmp_name"][$x]);
```

then replace the last line with something like

```
'SourceFile' => $newPNG  //possibly should be 'Body' not 'SourceFile' here?
```

I have found lots of ways to do this by making a new file using Imagick and GD but can't find a way to do the conversion and hand or stream the data straight to s3. Is this possible?

Comment: Should be able to write the output to the `php://memory` stream to avoid creating an actual file.

Comment: Related (dup?) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189368/creating-an-image-without-storing-it-as-a-local-file

Comment: thanks both, the dup had the answer for jpeg, png essentially same answer.